# jQuery UI dialog modal set to true doesn't work for radiobuttons

Tags: jquery-ui, dialog, modal-dialog, jquery-ui-dialog

When the dialog is set to modal it should disable all input elements, but I tried a simple example with a textbox and a radiobutton. When the dialog is opened the text-input is disabled as expected, but i still can check the radiobutton.
I used the example from the jQuery-ui demo and a simple html with just a input-textbox and the radio.

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Test</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="dialog-message" title="Download complete" style="display:none">
            <p>
                <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-check" style="float:left; margin:0 7px 50px 0;"></span>
                Your files have downloaded successfully into the My Downloads folder.
            </p>
            <p>
                Currently using <b>36% of your storage space</b>.
            </p>
        </div>
        <input type="text"/>
        <input type="radio" onClick="showDialog();"/>
        <input type="radio"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

And the jQuery:

```
function showDialog(){
   jQuery(function() {
       jQuery( "#dialog-message" ).dialog({
            position: 'center',
            zIndex: 4001,
            draggable: false,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                Ok: function() {
                    jQuery( this ).dialog( "close" );
                }
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: [Here's a fiddle with your code](http://jsfiddle.net/qCQ7b/). Do you see the issue there?

Comment: In the fiddle everything works as expected, but when I try the same code in my FF when the dialog pops up I can still check the second radiobutton.

Comment: I tried another, complexer scenario. Now i can't visibly check the radiobutton, but the onclick-event still fires. When I try this in the fiddle example everything works as it should.

Comment: I noticed your `head` tag wasn't opened--Could that have something to do with it?

Comment: No it just got lost with the copy and paste. In my example the html is valid.

Comment: Maybe it's a Mozilla Firefox problem (my current version: 8.0.1).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem solved. It had to do with the css. Because I didn't use the default css or css created with theme roller I forgot to define the styling for ui-widget-overlay. After I copied the ovelay-styling from the jquery-ui css everything worked fine.

the css:

```
   .ui-widget-overlay { 
         position: absolute; 
         top: 0; 
         left: 0; 
         width: 100%; 
         height: 100%; 
   }
   .ui-widget-overlay { 
         background: #666666 url(ui-bg_diagonals-thick_20_666666_40x40.png) 50% 50% repeat; 
         opacity: .50;
         filter:Alpha(Opacity=50); 
   }
```