# JQuery UI modal dialog doesn't cover all elements in page

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, modal-dialog, jquery-ui-dialog

I saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8396693/jquery-ui-dialog-modal-set-to-true-doesnt-work-for-radiobuttons) and act as it states, however it doesn't solve my problem. I have some `<ul><li></li></ul>` menus created with the free version of [CSS3 Menu](http://www.css3menu.com/). When I open the JQuery UI modal dialog, the dialog doesn't cover these menues and they stay on top of the darkness and the dialog itself. What should I do?

the .css of one of my menues is as the following:

```
ul#ptUsersMenu,ul#ptUsersMenu ul{
margin:0;list-style:none;padding:0;background-color:#dedede;border-width:1px;border-style:solid;border-color:#5f5f5f;-moz-border-radius:5px;-webkit-border-radius:5px;border-radius:5px;}

ul#ptUsersMenu ul{
display:none;position:absolute;right:0;top:100%;-moz-box-shadow:-3.5px 3.5px 5px #000000;-webkit-box-shadow:-3.5px 3.5px 5px #000000;box-shadow:-3.5px 3.5px 5px #000000;background-color:#303030;border-width:2px;border-radius:6px;-moz-border-radius:6px;-webkit-border-radius:6px;border-color:#FFF;padding:0 10px 10px;}

ul#ptUsersMenu li:hover>*{
display:block;}

ul#ptUsersMenu li{
position:relative;display:block;white-space:nowrap;font-size:0;float:left;}

ul#ptUsersMenu li:hover{
z-index:1;}

ul#ptUsersMenu{
font-size:0;position:relative;display:inline-block;zoom:1;padding:0;
*display:inline;}

* html ul#ptUsersMenu li a{
display:inline-block;}

ul#ptUsersMenu>li{
margin:0;}

ul#ptUsersMenu a:active, ul#ptUsersMenu a:focus{
outline-style:none;}

ul#ptUsersMenu a{
display:block;vertical-align:middle;text-align:center;text-decoration:none;font:12px Tahoma,Geneva,sans-serif;color:#000;text-shadow:#FFF 0 0 1px;cursor:pointer;padding:5px 1px 5px 1px;background-color:#ffbe18;background-image:url("../Images/css3menu/mainbk.png");background-repeat:repeat;background-position:0 0;border-width:0 0 0 1px;border-style:solid;border-color:#C0C0C0;}

ul#ptUsersMenu ul li{
float:none;margin:10px 0 0;}

ul#ptUsersMenu ul a{
text-align:right;padding:4px;background-color:#303030;background-image:none;border-width:0;border-radius:5px;-moz-border-radius:5px;-webkit-border-radius:5px;font:12px Tahoma;color:#fff;text-decoration:none;text-shadow:#FFF 0 0 0;}

ul#ptUsersMenu li:hover>a,ul#ptUsersMenu li a.pressed{
background-color:#968eff;border-color:#C0C0C0;border-style:solid;color:#000;text-shadow:#FFF 0 0 1px;background-image:url("../Images/css3menu/mainbk.png");background-position:0 100px;text-decoration:none;}

ul#ptUsersMenu img{
border:none;vertical-align:middle;margin-left:5px;}

ul#ptUsersMenu span{
display:block;overflow:visible;background-position:left center;background-repeat:no-repeat;padding-left:0px;}

ul#ptUsersMenu ul li:hover>a,ul#ptUsersMenu ul li a.pressed{
background-color:#ffff7f;background-image:none;color:#000;text-decoration:none;text-shadow:#FFF 0 0 0;}

ul#ptUsersMenu li.topfirst>a{
border-width:0;border-radius:4px 0 0 4px;-moz-border-radius:4px 0 0 4px;-webkit-border-radius:4px;-webkit-border-top-right-radius:0;-webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:0;}

ul#ptUsersMenu li.toplast>a{
border-radius:0 4px 4px 0;-moz-border-radius:0 4px 4px 0;-webkit-border-radius:0;-webkit-border-top-right-radius:4px;-webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:4px;}
```

and I call the dialog like this:

```
$("#divDialog").dialog({
            modal: true,
            show: "fade",
            hide: "clip",
            zIndex: 400000
        });
```

Comment: Sounds like you have a z-index problem, increase it for the dialog or decrease it in the menu.

Comment: I did. Now the z of dialog is 400000! doesn't work... I've set the z of dialog as an option like this `zIndex: 400000` am I correct?!

Comment: You need to include enough code to reproduce your problem or we can only make guesses. A functional demo on jsbin.com or jsfiddle.net would also be helpful.

Comment: the .css of menus are huge. however I put one of the here. As you'll see, there is just one `z-index` in this file which is 1...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it! I added `style="z-index:1"` to the top `<ul>` definitions of my menues and the bugs fixed...

Thank you all for your suggestions.